# XUbuntu & Konsole: Right Click -> Open File Manager opens VLC instead of Thunar

Tags: kubuntu, xubuntu, konsole

I am running XUbuntu 20.04.

I have installed konsole and use it instead of the default console that comes with XUbuntu.

When I right click on a konsole, there is an option to "Open File Manager".

This is convenient. However, when I click it, VLC opens in some file-explorer mode rather than thunar, my default file manager.

Is there a way to tell konsole to use thunar rather than VLC?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This took a bit of additional work to replicate your environment (Konsole + ZSH), but here's what you need to do to make it work:

0. Open Konsole (if it's not already open)
1. Set the default application for `inode/directory`:

   ```
   appname=$(ls -A1 /usr/share/applications/|grep -i thunar) && sed -i "/inode\/directory/d" ~/.config/mimeapps.list;echo "inode/directory=$appname" >> ~/.config/mimeapps.list
   ```

   <sub>**Note:** This will create a new file in `~/.config` for default MIME types.</sub>
2. Set the default `xdg-mime` value for directories:

   ```
   xdg-mime default org.kde.thunar.desktop inode/directory
   ```
3. Set/Reset the preferred applications:

   ```
   exo-preferred-applications
   ```
4. Set the File Manager to "Thunar" (with the proper icon, not the "No Entry" symbol):
   [image: Set the File Manager]
5. Restart Konsole
6. Test things work correctly with a right-click ⇢ File Manager:
   [image: Launching Thunar (instead of Catfish)]

Now you should be good to go

Comment: This did not work. I followed the steps carefully but VLC still launches. I noticed a line in .config/mimeapps.list "inode/directory=exo-file-manager.desktop;". I changed it to the thunar line, and it reverted back after running exo-preferred-applications.  I tried manually changing it and not running that program, but it made no difference.

Comment: Actually, this seems to have worked. Today I tried the button on a whim and it opened Thunar. I don't recall if I restarted my computer since my last post. In either case, with the addition of some time and maybe a restart, this did the trick. Thank you!